# How do I prevent user from adding a duplicate entry into a MySQL database?

Tags: java, mysql, database

I am working on an inventory database program using Java. I wrote a method that adds new product and quantity to the database. I am stuck on how I can prevent user from adding a duplicate entry to the database.
If the user enters a name that already exists in the database, the program should display an error message and show the main menu again. The program should not ask the user to enter the data again. The program should not replace the existing entry.
Thanks in advance!

```
public static void addData() {
    try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(db_url, user, password)) {

        String product = stringInput("Please enter the name of the product to store in inventory");
        int quantity = intInput("Please enter the quantity of the product");

        String addProduct = "INSERT INTO inventory VALUES (?,?)";
        PreparedStatement insertProduct = conn.prepareStatement(addProduct);

        insertProduct.setString(1, product);
        insertProduct.setInt(2, quantity);

        insertProduct.executeUpdate();
        conn.close();

        } catch(SQLException sqle){
            sqle.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }


    }
```

Comment: you  can search you entire database before enter a new data..if it is found then you can leave  it

Comment: The most reliable way is a `UNIQUE` constraint at the database level. All other measures suffer from [race conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition).

Comment: Use keys to restrict duplicate entries like use UNIQUE.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was extremely helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define UNIQUE constraint in your DB. Then if a duplicate entry is added it will throw an `SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException`. Catch the exception and handle the error in your app.

May not be applicable to you, but just for your information `spring-data` exposes `org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException` for achieving the same. When the same issue encountered spring-data wraps the underneath exception and re-throws a `DataIntegrityViolationException` so that the client can handle them inside the Error handling aspect using `@ControllerAdvice`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I got it to work!

Answer (score 0):

you must query inventory table first to check if product name already exist, something like this

"select i.id from inventory where name=?"

then check with if clause that query has result or not, if true then do whatever needed, like show error...

Answer (score 0):

In that case create a id column in your table and which should be unique or primary key. And handle exception  `SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException` to show the error message on app display.